# Finitely generated groups without the minimal condition on subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

**Definition**

A group $G$ is said to satisfies the *minimal condition* on subgroups iff every descending chain of subgroups stops after a finite number of steps.

I know Novikon and Adjan proved that the Burnside group $F/F^m$ (where $F$ is a free group of finite rank $n>0$ and $m$ is an odd integer grower than $4381$) is infinite and satisfies the minimal condition on abelian subgroups. Obviously it is countable.

**Question:** Does the Burnside group $F/F^m$ satisfies the minimal condition on subgroups?

I think the question can be reformulated in the following way:

> Is there a finitely generated group $G$ with finite odd exponent such that $G$ do not satisfies to minimal condition on subgroups?

Comment: I think the Burnside group $B(d,m)$ of large (odd?) exponent $m$ and $d\ge 2$ generators contains a copy of $B(\infty,m)$ and thus fails to satisfy min. Actually I even think it fails to satisfy min-n. Most likely it follows from some result of Olshanski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wreath product of two Tarski monsters. (I think.)